# How to change the UIPickerView text color?

Tags: uipickerview, swift4

The default UIPickerView color for text is black. There has been some updates to the language in Swift4. I have found my own solution and answered below.

Answer (score 39):

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    return NSAttributedString(string: data[row], attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow])        
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You could use:

```
pickerView.setValue(UIColor.yellow, forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

This will only change the color for the currently selected row.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866686/5306470

Comment: This will only change the color as you move the picker view for me.

Answer (score 12):

**Updated for Swift 5:**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    return NSAttributedString(string: parksPickerData[row], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In storyboard you can add `textColor` to Key Path:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have a project with PickerViews and DatePickers (inside a TableViewCell), and I had to use a different sentence for each case.

For PickerViews:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let titleData = "data"
        let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray])

        return myTitle
    }
```

For DatePicker:

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.lightGray, forKey: "textColor")
```